# From the App ID of a deployed App in the Teams Tenant Custom App Store, how do we find the original Azure App ID that was in the Manifest file?

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

Once a custom Teams App is deployed in a tenant from an app package, it appears with a new App ID (the app store App ID).  It appears that all traces of the Teams app package/ Manifest file used to upload are now lost to the Teams admin who uploaded the app package;  at least there is no way to find the app package that was uploaded.

From the Manage App Listing in the Teams Admin Portal, how do we find the original Azure App ID that was in the Manifest file that was part of the app package used to create the published app?

If not from the Teams Admin Portal, is there a path to trace from the App Store App ID (available after app is published) via the Graph to the associated entries in Azure AD, to the original App ID, and thence the bot, that was in the Manifest file?

If you have a number of apps with similar names from the same publisher, it appears next to impossible to back track to which of the multiple Teams bot the published application is using.

Answer (score 1):

Using Teams in the browser will give you a lot more info on this. For instance, when you go to a bot in a 1-1 chat, it will give an address like:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/apps/[GUID1]/sections/conversations?slug=28:[GUID2]`

`[GUID1]` *is* the app's ID as listed in the app's original manifest file. However, that only gives you the *Team App Id*, which is NOT the same as the Bot's ID. In some cases, the documentation *suggests* using the same Id for both your bot id and your team app id, but it's not a hard and fast rule at all.

To get the *bot id* you can try a similar trick though - use the browser tools, and in the bot 1-1 chat, use the `inspect` option to query the html. Look for an element called `virtual-repeat`. It will have a property called `conversation-id` which will look something like this:

`[Guid1]_[Guid2]`. `[GUID1]` is your own personal AzureAD ObjectId, `[GUID2]` is the bot's id.

However, you haven't stated why you need this bot id - perhaps explain what you're trying to do, and someone can help to approach that.

Comment: <<[GUID1] is the app's ID as listed in the app's original manifest file. However, that only gives you >>

I think you mean GUID2 here as GUID 1 is the App Store ID

Comment: As to why we need the bot ID:   As an ISV we created several test/uat/prod bots for a customer and sent them the app package. Customer modified the manifest a bit to change the logo, display name etc.  Now one of the apps is not working and Customer does not know which App in the store points to which of our various bots etc.

Comment: Ahh ok, that's an interesting challenge indeed. I hope my answer was able to help?

Answer (score 0):

For those admins with access to PowerShell  (Import-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams / Connect-MicrosoftTeams etc), the Get-TeamsApp commandlet will provide a list of all installed Tenant Apps as well as their External ID (which is the App ID listed in the Manifest file, which is the same as the Bot ID)

The item marked 1 is the External ID (Bot Application ID) and the Item marked 2 is the App Installation ID (as appears in the Teams Admin Portal -> Manage Apps, Select App, About-> App ID.

Microsoft should consider just displaying the two IDs alongside in the Teams Admin Portal itself.

[image]